# Can you use variables in resources block in Azure Devops?

Tags: azure-devops

In Auzure Devops, Can I use variables in the resources block? I am not having success.

```
variables:
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-20.04'
  repository: 'custom-forms-repo' # can be any name you want


resources:
  repositories:
  - repository: ${{ variables.repository }}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't.

When defining a resource in the YAML, you must specify the explicit values to each item of the resource. It is not support using variables to specify the values on the resource.